# correct location for putting the runtime jar file dependency

Tags: grails

the dependencies specified in the build config file of my grails application is as follows:

```
dependencies {
    // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.19'
    runtime 'org.imgscalr:imgscalr-lib:4.2'
    runtime 'net.authorize:anet-java-sdk:1.4.6'
    //runtime 'net.authorize:anet-java-sdk:1.8.1'   
    runtime 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1'
}
```

I need to upgrade a library i.e replace this line

```
runtime 'net.authorize:anet-java-sdk:1.4.6'
```

with

```
runtime 'net.authorize:anet-java-sdk:1.8.1'
```

I think i also need to put the jar file at the correct location since it is specified as a runtime dependency. I have downloaded the correct jar file i.e anet-java-sdk-1.8.1.jar. I only need to know the correct location to put this file into. Can you tell me the correct location in the grails project structure where i should put this jar file and also if there is anything else i need to do for correct upgrade of this library? I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you put in *BuildConfig.groovy* the following

```
runtime 'net.authorize:anet-java-sdk:1.8.1'
```

grails will search the library in the repositories you have defined (generally just above) in the part `grails.project.dependency.resolution.repositories` so you do not have to do anything and if you're using a standard library, it will be found in maven central and be downloaded for you.

If you do not use a open-source library or it is not pushed to any repo you can access, you need to download the jar file and put it under the `lib/` folder and grails will add this file in the classpath

You can read more about [dependency resolution](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/conf.html#dependencyResolution) (be sure to change the version with the one you're using, link is for 2.5.0) and all the settings that can be changed